# аудентификация и авторизация клиент приложения на сервере через api

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста, я в android новичек не могу сделать аутентификацию и авторизацию клиент приложения, авторизация и получение данных происходит путем post запросов по ссылке (через API), в данный момент у меня есть класс авторизации и проверки введенных данных. не могу разобраться как сделать хеширование пароля в md5 и отправку запроса на сервер вида login,md5(password) [POST:login,pass]
(login=admin&pass=21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3)

класс авторизации и проверки

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    private Button btn_log;
    private TextView loginLocked;
    private TextView attempts;
    private TextView numberOfAttempts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_log);
    }



    public void Btn_log (View view) {

        // Если введенные логин и пароль будут словом "admin",
        // показываем Toast сообщение об успешном входе:
        if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
                password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вход выполнен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Выполняем переход на другой экран:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        // В другом случае выдаем сообщение с ошибкой:
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Неправильные данные!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Совершенно неясно что вы хотите увидеть в ответе и к чему приложенный код. Есть ли у вас сервер, готовый провести эту самую авторизацию. Что вы уже пробовали делать и где именно проблема возникла. Перечитайте внимательно свой вопрос, взгляните на него глазами не имеющего понятия о чем вы пишете человека, и исправьте так, чтоб можно было объективно и конкретно на него ответить, желательно не задавая дополнительных вопросов

Comment: сервер уже готов для проведения такого запроса, вопрос в данном случае в том как введенный пароль в поле EditText захешировать в формате md5, логин не трогать и отправить данный Post запрос на адресс по https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окучивание пароля в md5 можно подсмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846484/md5-hashing-in-android)

С отправкой веселее. Берем библиотеку retrofit, которая сделает кучу работы за нас, подключаем к проекту. Описываем интерфейс для работы с сервером:

```
public interface API{

    @POST("index.php")
    public Call<String> login(@Query("login") String login, @Query("password") String password)
}
```

Аннотация POST указывает тип запроса, в скобках относительный url файла, к которому обращаться. Параметры помечаем аннотацией Query, в скобках имя поля, в которое в запросе положат значение параметра. Возвращать все методы должны объект класса Call из библиотеки Retrofit. Он дженерик с типом возвращаемого запросом значения. Чтобы привести содержимое ответа к этому типу нужен Conventer и той же библиотеки, а этот конвентер должен возвращаться абстрактной фабрикой конвентеров. В последнем предложении если ничего не понятно не страшно, просто делаем вот так:

```
private final factory = new Converter.Factory() {
        @Override 
        public Converter<ResponseBody, String> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Array<Annotation> annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
            return new Converter { 
                 @Override
                 public String convert(ResponceBoy value){
                       return String(value.bytes());
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ну и остается только сказать библиотеке Retrofit сделать из нашего интерфейса полноценный рабочий объект

```
private String baseUrl = "http://myserv.com/"
private API api = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(factory)
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .build()
        .create(API::class)
```

Теперь вызываем метод сгенерированного библиотекой объекта, получаем объект запроса. Выполняем его, ответ автоматом преобразуется в строку с помощью конвентора и остается лишь парсить ее

```
Call<String> call = api.login(login, password);
String result = call.execute();
```

`execute` выполнит запрос в том же потоке, где был запущен. То есть его в главном потоке вызывать нельзя. Можно вместо него использовать `call.enqueue(callback)`, тогда запрос выполнится в параллельном потоке, а коллбэк - в основном.

Там еще куча веселостей, но для начала хватит